# Gradle plugin specifying default extension values

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I plan to write custom plugin wrapping several code quality gradle plugins. The logic is simple: using this custom quality I want to enforce "default" standards for all our projects. On the other hand, I want all the wrapped plugins still to be customizable (for example, I'd like to set PMD plugin with "basic" ruleset by default, but definitely I do not want to limit anyone to add addinitional rulesets).

What is the recommended strategy to cascade the extensions?

- Should I do project.create({extension}) for all the plugins, check values if the values are set and default them (and how would I distinguish default from plugin extension and the default value set by the user?)
- Should I create myOwnExtension and set the values of the wrapped plugins extensions from this custom one?
- Is there any other way how to automatically do the cascade?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply a plugin that uses `project.afterEvaluate` then look for the plugin programmatically and if it's applied then check for the `pmd` block and configure as needed. If the plugin is not applied then apply the plugin and set the defaults for the block.

```
apply plugin: "groovy"

group = 'com.jbirdvegas.q41683529'
version = '0.1'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

class PmdWrapper implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project target) {
        target.afterEvaluate {
            def pmdPlugin = target.plugins.findPlugin(PmdPlugin)
            // check if the plugin is already applied if not apply it
            if (!pmdPlugin) {
                target.plugins.apply(PmdPlugin)
            }
            // get a reference to the extension and use it to manipulate the values
            println target.pmd.ruleSets
            setValues(target.pmd as PmdExtension)
            println target.pmd.ruleSets

            println "Now configured ruleSets: ${(target.pmd as PmdExtension).ruleSets}"
        }
    }

    static setValues(PmdExtension pmd) {
        // here you can set the values or add or manipulate as needed
        if (!pmd.ruleSets.contains('basic') || !pmd.ruleSets.contains('braces')) {
            pmd.ruleSets << "basic" << "braces"
        }
        // blah for other values
    }
}

apply plugin: PmdWrapper
task nothing {}
```

Then you can see the result of the pmd plugin being configured

```
$ ./gradlew -b build_simple.gradle nothing -q
[java-basic]
[java-basic, basic, braces]
Now configured extension: [java-basic, basic, braces]
```