# Gradle Plugin Development (Java code): Update extension properties for Internal applied Plugin

Tags: gradle, plugins, gradle-plugin

I am new to Gradle plugin development and I am writing the code in Java (not Groovy).
My question is somewhat similar to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41683529/gradle-plugin-specifying-default-extension-values).

I am developing a plugin which applies another [plugin](https://github.com/jeremylong/dependency-check-gradle) and trying to provide a wrapper by customizing few configurations. 
The applied plugin has few extensions like `dataExtension`, `dependencyCheck` extension for which I can configure values in build.gradle file ([sample](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-gradle/configuration.html) configurations).

Now I want to configure these values from my custom plugin instead of build.gradle file. So I want to re-use these extensions and configuration values of dependencyCheck plugin in my plugin

I tried the following after applying the plugin programmatically:

1. Directly used the properties for the plugin:

   ```
   DependencyCheckPlugin p = project.getPlugins.apply(DependencyCheckPlugin.class)
   p.setProperty("dependencyCheck.outputDirectory", project.getBuildDir());
   ```

This is not working as expected.

2. Directly set properties to project

   ```
   DependencyCheckPlugin p = project.getPlugins.apply(DependencyCheckPlugin.class)
   project.setProperty("dependencyCheck.outputDirectory", project.getBuildDir());`
   ```

I got error message project doesn’t have the property `dependencyCheck.outputDirectory`.

3. Tried to get Extension of the applied plugin and set properties

   ```
   DependencyCheckExtension depExtn = (DependencyCheckExtension)project.getExtensions().getByType(DependencyCheckExtension.class);
   depExtn.setAutoUpdate(false);
   depExtn.setOutputDirectory(extn.getOutputdir());
   depExtn.setFormat(ReportGenerator.Format.ALL);
   ```

I got error message saying that the Extension is not found in this project.

Any suggestion on how I can configure the internal plugin from external plugin?

Comment: Does my answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've implemented in the following way:

```
package lol;

import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.owasp.dependencycheck.gradle.DependencyCheckPlugin;
import org.owasp.dependencycheck.gradle.extension.DependencyCheckExtension;

public class LolPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {

        final DependencyCheckPlugin dcp = project.getPlugins().apply(DependencyCheckPlugin.class);
        project.getLogger().lifecycle("LOL {}", dcp);

        final DependencyCheckExtension dce = (DependencyCheckExtension) project.getExtensions().findByName("dependencyCheck");
        project.getLogger().lifecycle("LOL {}", dce);
        project.getLogger().lifecycle("LOL {}", dce.getAutoUpdate());
        dce.setAutoUpdate(true);
        project.getLogger().lifecycle("LOL {}", dce.getAutoUpdate());

    }

}
```

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/46267478)'s the whole example.

Comment: it was easy to setAutoUpdate. But found difficult to update the internal DataExtension (Extension inside DependencyCheckExtension). Found it later to use ExtensionAware interface to do it.